# Keeping the Angular2 router's hands off of the browser's address bar

Tags: url, angular, browser, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I'm building a single-page Angular 2.2.0 application which will be part of an embedded website. The site will have half a dozen pages, with the Angular SPA at `/application.html`. The application will show/hide various components at various times, which I'm driving using the router.

I want that `/application.html` URL to be maintained, since I don't need users to be able to bookmark locations inside the SPA, the web server can't be configured to map "not found" URLs to somewhere else, and it would make the SPA better coexist with the rest of the website. Unfortunately, this isn't how the Angular router is designed: it reeeeally wants to play with the browser's address bar.

I've worked around two consequences of this; specifically I'm using the `skipLocationChange` property when my code jumps to a new location, and I'm not using the `<a routerLink=...` tool to have links in my templates. However, there's a third problem I haven't worked around: Angular clearing the address bar when it starts up.

Angular's router seems to need the address bar's initial value to be equal to the `base` value given in the host page. If I have the usual `<base href="/">`, then the address bar is initially set to `example.com/`. If I instead use `<base href="/application.html">`, then the address bar is initialized to `example.com/application.html/` (note that trailing `/`; close but no cigar). This is all very frustrating; there's no reason use of the router should require ceding control of the address bar.

Is there a way to keep the Angular 2 router from messing with the browser's address bar? Or, if I don't use the router, is there a way to have program state determine whether various components appear and disappear? (The latter would actually be the best of all possible worlds; the router system is pretty constraining.)

Comment: Set the useHash extra option to true when creating the router modue: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks; that does clean things up, but there's still schmutz in the address bar.

Comment: The whole point of the router is to map URLs to components, and to navigate through URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routings benefit comes from state management through the URL. Since you don't need that state management, I just wouldn't use routing at all. Load your "pages/views" through components with

```
<page-one *ngIf="showPageOne"></page-one>, etc....
```

You still get the benefit of angular not loading components that aren't in use. Otherwise, I would use hash strategy.

Comment: So, I'd need to list every possible component to be shown in the parent component's template, with their visibility governed by some value(s), right? (But, I currently have to do the same in the router configuration)

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Either way, you'll have a list of every possible component somewhere in the app. Whether you're using routing or not.

Comment: Any comment on the proposed [NgComponentOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13383) feature?

Comment: Just seeing it. I wouldn't find much use for it, but given your situation, it could make things a little "cleaner"